# how to navigate to details page after search in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout, querying

I'm learning Flutter and I'm trying to continue working on this guy project https://github.com/rajayogan/flutterfirestore-instantsearch/blob/master/lib/main.dart ( full code ) but he doesn't have onTap or onPress function that navigate to each details page after search so I'm wondering how to implement that.

This project is about querying data from firebase and displaying on Flutter app.

Can anybody take a quick look at his code and help me how to create on Tap function that can navigate to each details page? Thanks

Currently the app look like this

[image]

I have this fields in my firebase database,

[image]

This is his Youtube video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0szEJiCUtMM&t=198s

Comment: I have uploaded my firebase screenshot. I want to display all the information like imageURL, created and content in details page.

Answer (score 0):

Widget buildResultCard has data from search result so you can just wrap it in a Gesture Detector or Inkwell widget and navigate it to any page you want. Here is an example of me forwarding the data to MyPage.

```
Widget buildResultCard(data) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
       Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPage(data: data));
      );
    },
    child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Text(data['businessName'],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                )
            )
        )
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I just uploaded my firebase pic so can you help me how I can show those information in another page when ever the user tap on the result. thanks

Comment: Yes you just need to pass this data to another page like I have shown you in the example and then display it in widgets you have for example Text(widget.data['content']).

Comment: Widget buildResultCard(data) this method has data being passed to it so you can further pass data to another page (your detail page) and then show data the same way businessName is being shown in your Card Widget. If you don't know how to pass data to another page please refer to Flutter documentation "Send data to a new screen"